# Should ViewModels contain Models? (ASP.NET, Entity Framework)

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

Should view models contain models directly as shown below?

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public Car Car { get; set; }          // Car model
    public Driver Driver { get; set; }    // Driver model
    public Photo Photo { get; set; }      // Photo model

    public List<Skill> Skills { get; set; }   // List of Skill model
}
```

or should view models contain another view models:

```
{
    public CarViewModel CarViewModel { get; set; }
    public DriverViewModel DriverViewModel { get; set; }
    public PhotoViewModel PhotoViewModel { get; set; }

    public List<SkillViewModel> Skills { get; set; }
}
```

What is the best practice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what you are doing, but normally, the second option is the best practice, assuming all of the objects inside the Viewmodel are somehow actually displayed in the View.

Also take into aspect that your ViewModel items represent the thing on the UI, and the Model represents the business logic.

So, your UI-Artefacts (ViewModel objects) are not necessarily associatable to one domain object (Business Logic Object).

So, in your example,
"Photo" or "Skills" don't seem to be a logical object in that matter.

They exists on the ViewModel to be displayed, as UI Artefacts, but in the logical domain they would more likely be a property of a logical object, maybe the driver, or something.

Comment: What are the disadvantages of the first approach?

Comment: Advantages: Having a Viemodel close to the ui lets you databind things as the ui displays them, but that is not necessarily the logical model you are displaying.
Imagine calculated values that are not part of the logical model (i.e. "last change 3 days ago"). 

Imagine UI-Artefacts that are in a tableline but are really consisting of information regarding multiple logical objects. Imagin Commands that Buttons do.
Doing that lets multiple UIs use the same model and make the UI replaceable.

Its called MVVM (Model View ViewModel)

Comment: Disadvantages: If your display technique is pretty close to the model this (MVVM approach) usually lets you write a lot of boilerplace code to transfer data->model->viemodel